# Same mathematical fonts with LuaTeX and ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, luatex, context

I use LuaLaTeX to compile my documents with this in the preamble :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[urw-garamond,uppercase=upright,greeklowercase=upright]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}
 $f(x)=x^2+2x+4$
\end{document}
```

I try to do the same with ConTeXt, but the result is not quite the same, in particular the letter x :

```
 \setuppapersize[A4]
 \loadtypescriptfile[mathdesign]
 \setupbodyfont[garamond]
 \starttext
 Some random text and \math{f(x)=x^2+2x+4}
 \stoptext
```

The compilation gives me this :

```
   system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded
  (/home/fab/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv)
  system          > files > jobname 'demo1', input './demo1', result 'demo1'
  fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
  languages       > language 'en' is active
  (/home/fab/demo1.tex (/home/fab/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context /base/type-imp-mathdesign.mkiv)
  fonts           > typescripts > unknown library 'loc'
  fonts           > typescripts > unknown library 'garamond'
  fonts           > preloading latin modern fonts (third stage)
  {/home/fab/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm-math.map}{/home  /fab/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm-rm.map}{/home/fab/texlive /2013/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/context/mkiv-base.map}
  fonts           > 'fallback modern rm 12pt' is loaded
```

Comment: You are only setting the text font, not the math font.

Comment: What do you expect? You are using two entirely different fonts: URW Garamond in what appears to be Type1 format, and EB Garamond as OpenType. I couldn’t test your Latex code since texlive lacks the garamondx package. But these fonts are unlikely to be metrically compatible, let alone visually identical.
Also, EB Garamond is not a math font.
Lastly, I suggest getting rid of the ``\enableregime`` directive since it is anachronistic in 2013.

Comment: I modified my code using `\loadtypescriptfile[mathdesign]\loadtypescriptfile[garamond]\setupbodyfont[Mathdesign Garamond]` but `typescripts > unknown library 'garamond'typescripts > unknown library 'Mathdesign Garamond'`

Comment: You need an up to date ConTeXt. The ConTeXt that ships with texlive does not have the required typescripts. With ConTeXt minimals, try: `\loadtypescriptfile[mathdesign] \setupbodyfont[garamond]`.

Comment: My guess is that you are using an old version of ConTeXt that does not include a typescript for garamond. You need to copy the appropriate lines from the [current type-imp-mathdesign.mkiv](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/type-imp-mathdesign.mkiv) file. This file relies on a corresponding [font goodies](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/fonts/mdugm-math.lfg) file, but that needs a newer version of Context.

Comment: @ Aditya I installed a recent version of context standalone distribution and followed your advice, it works with the Garamond font but not with the Charter fonts ! `{/home/fab/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/context/mkiv-base.map}
! Math error: parameter \Umathquad\displaystyle is not set.`

Answer (score 1):

My setup: I use the latest ConTeXt minimals beta, and a full installation of texlive package on ArchLinux. I add `/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts` to the ConTeXt minimals TEXMF tree that allows me to use Texlive fonts with ConTeXt minimals.

For some reason (which I think has to do with the fact that `mdugm` fonts are in the `non-free` directory on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/non-free/tfm)), mathdesign garamond is not available on Arch Linux. So, the following example shows how to use Mathdesign charter:

```
\loadtypescriptfile[mathdesign]
\setupbodyfont[charter]

\starttext

Some random text and \math{f(x)=x^2+2x+4}

\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

In principle, the same method should work if you replace `charter` with `garamond`, but I haven't been able to test that since I do not have the fonts.